# ElasticSearch NEST - FieldValueFactorFunction score function outputting invalid json query

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest, elasticsearch.net

Let me preface this to say I'm newer to ElasticSearch and NEST, and may be doing something wrong. This is using NEST 7.6.2.
I'm following the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/function-score-query-usage.html) to create a `field_value_factor` score function containing a filter and weight using object initializer syntax, i.e.:

```
new FieldValueFactorFunction
{
    Field = "foo",
    Modifier = FieldValueFactorModifier.Log1P,
    Missing = 1,
    Filter = new MatchQuery
    {
        Field = "bar",
        Query = "1"
    },
    Weight = .2
}
```

However, at runtime it appears to output an invalid json format in the query itself:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "match": {
            "bar": {
                "query": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "foo",
        "missing": 1.0,
        "modifier": "log1p",
        "filter": {
            "match": {
                "bar": {
                    "query": "1"
                }
            }
        },
        "weight": 0.2
    },
    "weight": 0.2
}
```

Which fails with the error `field_value_factor query does not support [value]`. I do know the valid function syntax I'm trying to emulate is the following:

```
{
    "filter": {
        "match": {
            "bar": {
                "query": "1"
            }
        }
    },
    "field_value_factor": {
        "field": "foo",
        "missing": 1.0,
        "modifier": "log1p"
    },
    "weight": 0.2
}
```

Is this a bug in NEST/Elasticsearch.net? Is my syntax incorrect? Is there an alternate way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was apparently an issue in the version of NEST I was using. Updating the nuget package resolved it.